# Overloading + operator to mimic moving to the next node

Tags: c++

I would like to overload `+` so that when I have 'iterator' I can use `+` instead of `->next`.

What I mean is if I had something like:

```
mylist<int>::iterator n = test.begin();
n = n->next;
```

I'd like to go to the next element in the list using `n = n + 1`.

I tried to overload the operator in my node class.

```
mynode* operator+(size_t n) {
    size_t cnt = 0;
    mynode* count = this;
    while(cnt != n) {
        ++cnt;
        count = count->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

In my list class I have `typedef mynode<T>* iterator`.

Comment: What specifically is going wrong?

Comment: Why not simply implement an iterator for your linked list class? Its simple, is the common way to achieve this, and works for everithing.

Comment: Actually I think the operator isn't being called.

Comment: @Manu343726. I was trying to avoid this because I did not want to overload many other operators.

Comment: You're out of luck.  You can't overload operators unless at least one of the arguments is a class type.

Comment: How about you provide an SSCCE ( http://sscce.org/ ) that shows he problem, along with input, expected output, and actual output so we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the example seems like a `operator+` defined inside the class declaration, so the first `mynode` operand is omitted. On the other hand, the return type is wrong, should be `mynode`, not `mynode*`.

Comment: @Manu343726: Yes, I understand that.  But his intent is to overload the operator such that he can add an integer to a pointer (specifically `mynode<T>*`), and have it retrieve the `next` node pointer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley sorry. As I said before, I think the best solution is to implement an iterator.

Comment: @Manu343726: Clearly. Which is why I said he's out of luck when he said he was trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Manu343726. You're right. It wasn't as daunting as it seemed to implement an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think the operator isn't being called

The problem is that `n` in your example is a pointer (or an iterator with the pointer semantic), not an object. You cannot overload `operator +` on the pointer, only on the object itself. That is why the operator is not being called -- C++ has built-in operators for pointer arithmetic, which is what gets applied when your code runs.

To fix this problem you would need to provide your own iterator objects, which encapsulate the corresponding pointers. Then you would be able to override the `operator +` on your iterator, walking the list as needed, and returning a new iterator pointing to the correct element.

Comment: That said, it's bad form to implement `operator+` on an iterator that isn't RandomAccess. Instead, users should expect to use `std::advance` or (in C++11) `std::next` on such iterators instead of `operator+`. Although AFAIK that is just a style issue, there's no requirement that `operator+` on an iterator is O(1).